Handshake error in ASP.NET Core 6 application using Negotiate authentication
I have an ASP.NET Core 6 application that uses the Negotiate authentication scheme to authenticate using the Windows authentication (NTLM/Kerberos).
I'm configuring the authentication service like this:
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();
    
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
}

This works correctly on my local dev machine, however when I try to deploy it to a production server, something breaks.
In particular, once deployed if I try to call an endpoint marked with [Authorize] the browser correctly shows me the login prompt, but after entering my credentials the backend responds with a generic 500 error.
One important thing I noticed is that if I try to access the app from within the server itself by accessing via https://localhost the authentication works, but if I use the machine full machine URL, like: https://myserver.domain.local, it doesn't work and I get the 500 error.
So this might be something related to a network proxy or something like that? How can I debug this properly? I tried enabling all logging down to the "debug" level, and this is what I see when I get the error:

Connection id "0HN6OHVHNEJKS", Request id "0HN6OHVHNEJKS:00000007": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: An anonymous request was received in between authentication handshake requests.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
at  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

The stack trace seems to suggest I'm performing other connections during the handshake, but I checked in the browser Network panel and I don't have any extra pending connections.
Any ideas?

Could you please tell me how you host this application? Directly running or hosting it at IIS? If you host it inside the IIS, could you please share how you set the windows authe for it?

I self-host using Kestrel, and I figured out the issue (check my answer). Thanks for the input anyway

Well, I figured it out. Apparently if you are in a domain and you self-host the app as a Windows service you need to run this command, otherwise the service user cannot authenticate calls:
setspn -s HTTP/mymachine.mydomain.local mydomain\serviceuser

after this, it works correctly.
Interestingly, the official Microsoft Documentation on the subject says that this is only necessary in macOS/Linux environments, but I was on Windows Server and I still needed to do this.
